# Link for IWD OnePageCheckout

Tags: cart, checkout, onepage-checkout

I've installed magento extension IWD OnePageCheckout on my site. All links leading to checkout are properly redirecting to onepage checkout. However the link in the header cart is still linking to old checkout page. When I checked topcart.phtml page, I found this code written in it for cart page:

```
 <?php if($_cartQty && $this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout()): ?>                          
    <li>
        <span class="total">Total <strong><?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getSubtotal()) ?><?php if ($_subtotalInclTax = $this->getSubtotalInclTax()): ?> / <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_subtotalInclTax) ?> <?php echo Mage::helper('tax')->getIncExcText(true) ?><?php endif; ?></strong></span>
        <button class="checkout" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl ?>')"><?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?></button>
    </li>
<?php endif ?>
```

I think the `onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl ?>')"` part is causing the problem here. What should I write here so that it also properly redirects to One Page Checkout, instead of the default checkout page.

Comment: The Actual url of like `https://iwdextensions.com/demo/opc-ee/onepage/` Please check their Demo Site

Comment: Thanks. It worked. You can add this as an answer, i'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Actual Url will be for the IDW One Page Checkout will be as bellow.

`https://domain.com/opc-ee/onepage/`

So when you got url `checkout/onepage/index` then you have to change the url to `opc-ee/onepage`.

Hope this will help you.